# Windows command to download a file from URL

Tags: linux, windows, unix, cmd, powershell-2.0

I want to download a file using the windows command from url. I want to know if there is a command like **wget** in windows.

Thank you

Comment: And typing "wget for windows" or something similar into Google was too much to ask ...?

Comment: Refer This :https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing

Comment: What you intend to do, Is  it a simple file download or is it more complicated? For example, is the downloadable content password-protected, is it a "javascript-guarded" URL ( a click handler starts the download). Other complications are possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this PowerShell script:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile(“URL of file”,“Where save”)
```

Replace **URL of file** by URL, example as http://example.com/icon.png

**Where save** by path in your PC, such as C:\Users\User\Desktop\icon.png

Ex:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("https://example.com/data.txt","D:\FileDownloaded.txt");
```

(Sorry about my English, thanks)